Why does std::filesystem::remove() error_code return "unknown error" if the file does not exist?
I want to use the std::filesystem::remove() function to remove a file, and give an error if the file does not exist. Something like this:
std::error_code errorCode;
if (!std::filesystem::remove("<some file path>", errorCode))
{
    std::cout << "Could not delete file because " << errorCode.message();
}

However, if the file does not exist, this yields the message Could not delete file because unknown error.
My question is: Why doesn't this tell me that the file does not exist?
I interpret the documentation on cppreference to say that

The non-error_code version of the remove function returns false if the file does not exist, and throws an exception on other errors.
The error_code version returns false on any error, and stores the reason in the error_code. It never throws an exception.

Given that the error code just says "unknown error" when a file does not exist, it seems that this version gives less information than the non-error_code one? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding something?
I'm on Windows 11, using Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.11.2.

https://godbolt.org/z/YfPsPjEEf Could not delete file because: The operation completed successfully. :)

I tried this code on VS2022 Win10 and it looks like it's an implementation problem. If you call GetLastError inside the if then it's set correctly to 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND as per Microsoft's documentation.
Seems the implementation of __std_fs_remove doesn't correctly populate the error with the last error code set by DeleteFileW
If you try the following code, then you get the expected message:
auto err = GetLastError(); errorCode = std::error_code(err, std::system_category()); std::cout << "Could not delete file because " << errorCode.message() << " " << err;

@MarekR Maybe it's something with how CompilerExplorer interacts with the filesystem

@RaduC Yes, this works, thanks a lot! Is this issue reported somewhere so you can track it?

@gris_martin Not that I know of. You can certainly file a bug with Microsoft. All that I could find is this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/std::filesystem::remove-is-not-throwing/10684615?sort=newest but it doesn't seem directly related to what you reported.


I interpret the documentation on cppreference to say that

The non-error_code version of the remove function returns false if the file does not exist, and throws an exception on other errors.
The error_code version returns false on any error, and stores the reason in the error_code. It never throws an exception.


No, that would be inconsistent. Why should one overload treat "file does not exist" as an error and set ec, but the other one not treat it as an error?
For both functions, a non-existent file is not an error. Both functions return true if the file was removed successfully, return false if it didn't exist, and report an error (by throwing or setting ec) if an error occurred, (possible errors include a failure when checking whether the file exists, or failure to remove the file). The behaviour of the two overloads is consistent.
When an error is reported by throwing an exception, obviously there is no return value. When an error is reported by setting ec, the function still has to return something. The last sentence "The signature with argument ec returns false if an error occurs." is telling you what is returned in that case. It's not telling you that returning false always implies an error occurred.
Or put another way, it says that when an error occurs, it returns false. That's not the same as saying  that when it returns false, that means an error occurred.

Yes, I do think that's how it should be interpreted, and I'll mark this as accepted. Thank you!
However, I think the phrasing is a bit ambiguous. "The signature with argument ec returns false if an error occurs." could be interpreted both to mean that the signature returns false only on errors, and that it also returns false on errors.

I disagree. As I said in the last sentence of my answer, "if X then Y" does not mean that Y always implies X. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent

Or to put it yet another way, it does not say it returns false if and only if an error occurs.

@JonathanWakely You'd have to admit that the language is ambiguous coloquially. I can see that someone edited the cppreference page on Nov 15 (exactly when you replied, maybe after) to add to the notes that non existent p is not an error. Good answer, though! Consistency makes sense for this choice.

Since you did not tag the question with a specific OS, and want to know the generic answer, I will answer in an opinion-based way.
The C++ standard library depends on an implementation. Filesystems can vary. Your library implementation might think that "file does not exist" is not an error.
I do not have a print copy. The below is an extract from the latest draft of C++.

31.12.13.31 Remove [fs.op.remove]
bool filesystem::remove(const path& p);
bool filesystem::remove(const path& p, error_code& ec) noexcept;
1 Effects: If exists(symlink_status(p, ec)), the file p is removed as if
by POSIX remove(). [Note 1 : A symbolic link is itself removed, rather
than the file it resolves to. — end note]
2 Postconditions:
exists(symlink_status(p)) is false.
3 Returns: false if p did not
exist, otherwise true. The signature with argument ec returns false if
an error occurs.

You have might noticed that file is removed as if POSIX remove was called. Windows is not POSIX compliant. The Windows implementation of the library might have chosen another way of how to look on file removal.
update
To clarify things I think I need to elaborate on my answer a little more. Please consider the below possible implementation of the function.
bool            exists = false;
std::error_code e      = 0;

try {
 exists = ... /* check that a file exists */
 if(exists) {
  /* remove the file */
 }
}catch(...) {
 exists = false;
}

e = platform_specific_error_code;
return exists;

The return value error will be the error that platform had set before the return from the above implementation. This possible implementation is done according to standard wording. With my possible implementation you will get error return from the platform. So if you would had chosen my implementation over the implementation that you are using now, you would have get the above results.

It says "if exists". What happens if it does not exist?

@BoP see point 3 of the paragraph.

Yes, but is it an error that the file doesn't exist? The postconditions are fulfilled.

It doesn't say that the function only works on POSIX compliant systems, it just says that it should work the same way as POSIX remove() does? At least that's how I interpret it.

@BoP i did an update to the answer.

The reason std::filesystem::remove() returns "unknown error" on Windows when the file doesn’t exist is due to how some implementations of the standard library handle error codes for missing files. In this case, it may not map the error correctly, resulting in a vague message.
Solution:
Check if the error code is std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory, which explicitly represents "file not found":
std::error_code errorCode;
if (!std::filesystem::remove("<some file path>", errorCode)) {
    if (errorCode == std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory) {
        std::cout << "File does not exist.\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Could not delete file because " << errorCode.message();
    }
}

This works well for me, so probably for you aswell, if it doesn't work, feel free to ask me :D

https://godbolt.org/z/qav9Ydc9d

It does nothing in this case. If you'd tested the code, you'd see the errorCode is actually not set aka it stays 0 (no error).

Thank you for your answer! Sadly I come to the else branch and get the same message as in the question. Which OS and compiler are you using?

If this were the solution, the OP would have gotten a message like "No such file or directory", not "Unknown error"
